# STSで存在するはずのファイルを認識してくれない

Tags: eclipse, spring

SpringToolSuite4.4を利用しているときに問題が置きました。
SoruceTreeで更新の管理を行っています。

別のブランチを操作してから、再度ブランチを切り替えたところ、
「存在しているファイル」を認識しないため「Classがない」というエラー表示となります。

試しに新規ファイルを作成しようとすると「すでに存在している」というエラーとなります。

このような場合に、どうやってSTSにファイルを認識させることができるでしょうか？
STSを一度終了させてみたり、ファイル名を変更してみたりしましたが、認識してくれません。

よろしくお願いします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STSの外部で変更した内容をSTSに認識させるのは **右クリック > Refresh** です(ショートカットは <kbd>F5</kbd>)。

それとは別に、 `.java` ファイルがソースパスに入っていません。
正しい状態であれば、アイコンは下図のようなデザインになるはずです。
Maven でプロジェクト管理しているのであれば、プロジェクト(下図では"jaso8946"のアイコン)を **右クリック > Maven > Update Project** を選択してプロジェクトを再読み込みしてみてください(ショートカットキーは <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>)。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとうございます。
リフレッシュすることで表示させることができるようになりました。
ソースパスへの追加の処理もやってみました。`src/main/java` から表示されるようになったので大丈夫かと思います。
感謝です！